# Too many waiting Nginx workers Vs writing. Is that normal or indication of wrong configuration?

Tags: nginx

[Please see this graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pouAj.png)

As you can see on the image there are 66 waiting and two writing workers.. Any reason why there are so many idle workers?

Can we lower these waiting workers and only call them if needed? IF they are sitting there waiting for nothing then I guess it is a waste of resources.. How to configure nginx to only spawn necessary workers?

Comment: You only have 3 connections/sec, so you probably just have the initial worker count set too high for the load.

Comment: I have 2GB RAM and  1 CPU machine.. Do you think these values below should be lowered?
 
`worker_connections 4096;`

`worker_processes auto;`

`worker_rlimit_nofile 65535;`

Comment: What resources are being used? Why do you think anything is being wasted?

Comment: @MichaelHampton RAM? That's my guess. Is that normal?

Answer (score 1):

here is formula that might help.

> average amount of users served per second  =
>   worker_processes * worker_connections / (keepalive_timeout * 2)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7325211/tuning-nginx-worker-process-to-obtain-100k-hits-per-min